# I'm having a problem with a Facebook App I added to my Facebook Page it no longer works because of new CSP rules

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-apps

I'm having a problem with a Facebook App (Custom Facebook Tab) that I added to my Facebook Page. It no longer works because of new CSP (Content Security Policy) rules.

The app is basically a framed page served from the sites.google.com domain, it worked for many years but seems to have stopped working some time around May this year, i think due to the Chrome browsers changing their CSP policies.

When i try to view the app on Facebook, it just displays a grey square where the page content should be that shows the error message "This content is blocked, contact the site owner to fix the issue"

I tried it in the latest Firefox and the page works fine, its just the latest Chrome it doesnt work in.

I am the site owner, but i have no idea how to fix it. Does anyone know of a way around this problem, i.e displaying a Facebook app which consists of framed content from another site on your Facebook Page?

Comment: It looks like its a facebook bug, it seems like they didnt test whether tab apps would still work when they made the change to their CSP... check here for the bug on the Facebook bug tracker: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/593062641823417/